# Conditionally render <td> in a React component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This is a JSX gist I'm displaying on the page.

```
rows.push(
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>{this.state['Person Name'] && this.state['Person Name'][i]}</td>
            <td>{this.state['Amount'] && this.state['Amount'][i]}</td>
            {this.state['Memo'] && this.state['Memo'].length > 0 ? <td>{this.state['Memo'][i]}</td> : undefined}
            {this.state['Comment'] && this.state['Comment'].length > 0 ? <td>{this.state['Comment'][i]}</td> : undefined}
            {this.state['Incurred Date'] && this.state['Incurred Date'].length > 0 ? <td>{this.state['Incurred Date'][i]}</td> : undefined}
            {this.state['Entry Date'] && this.state['Entry Date'].length > 0 ? <td>{this.state['Entry Date'][i]}</td> : undefined}
            <td>{this.state['Billable'] && this.state['Billable'][i]}</td>
            <td>{this.state.fileName === 'expenses.csv' ? 'Expense' : 'Time'}</td>
          </tr>
        )
```

Somehow the conditions that are falsy still display empty `<td>`s to the table. What did I miss?

[image]

Empty columns are shown above.

Comment: That’s because you are doing conditions check inside td elements. Conditions check should be outside td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use ternary operators at all. Simply just chain `&&`'s.

```
{this.state.Memo && this.state.Memo[i] && <td>{this.state.Memo[i]}</td>}
{this.state.Comment && this.state.Comment[i] && <td>{this.state.Comment[i]}</td>}
{this.state['Incurred Date'] && this.state['Incurred Date'][i] && <td>{this.state['Incurred Date'][i]}</td>}
{this.state['Entry Date'] && this.state['Entry Date'][i] && <td>{this.state['Entry Date'][i]}</td>}
```

In addition, your array seems to be badly formatted:

```
// 2 separate variables for the same data?
this.memo = ['a', 'b'];
this.comment = ['comment', 'comment2'];

// Why not make it an array like this?
this.rows = [
    {
        Memo: 'a',
        Comment: 'comment'
    },
    {
        Memo: 'b',
        Comment: 'comment2'
    }
];
```

Then you can simply do:

```
this.rows.map(row => (
      <tr key={row.id}>
        <td>{row['Person Name']}</td>
        <td>{row['Amount']}</td>
        {this.state.hasMemos && <td>{row.Memo}</td>}
        ...
      </tr>
    )}
```

A `<td>` shouldn't be conditional on a row level, it should be conditional on a table level. **You can't simply skip TD's if there isn't data for that row, as it will throw off the whole row by shifting columns over**. You should either display N/A, an empty `<td></td>` for rows that may not have data, or hide them entirely on a table level via something like `this.state.hasMemos`, if there are any memos.

If you're using the new array structure I have listed, you can use this function to determine if any row has a memo:

```
this.array.some(row => row.Memo);
```

This will return true if any row has a Memo, thus either hiding the `<td>` for the entire table, or displaying it for every row.

Comment: I had wrong conditions in my logic. Now it's fixed. Thank you for this elaborate answer. For this table I uploaded two .csv files with different key names. Both have some commonly named key and some different ones. Here: 'Incurred Date,Memo,Person Name,Amount,Billable,Account' and 'Entry Date,Person Name,Comment,Billable,Amount'. Since I display the contents of both files in the same table I have to check for specific key names.

Comment: @ElAnonimo I definitely hope you take my suggestions to heart. `this.state['Comment'][i]` is an eyesore, and a terrible way of storing all the data in separate state variables.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to apply your suggestions to the code. Also this link may provide a better idea what's up with the rest of the code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608239/5524590 Each .csv file has multiple lines therefore multiple entries for the same state keys. Here's what one of them look like if you're curious: https://pastebin.com/KM21bJDp